# Can't pass row 999 in mysql database why?

Tags: mysql, database

So I hava a database (mysql) in my website with a table in it, in this table I have 10 columns for every row the first is an int primary key auto increase, the second one is the name that's unique they can't be the same, and the others are just text fields, so I have been entering data into it, the problem have come when I hit the 999 id mark that's the 999 row, I can't insert row 1000 it doesn't accept it at least I'm not able to see it in the table, and if I try to add it again it tells me that the name it already exists, so what can I do? Why Am I not able to add more rows?, why it thinks the name exists if the row with that name does not exists?
Can I get any advise from, in advance Thanks.

Comment: What type is the column, and what is its length?

Comment: Give your create table command syntax ,insert query

Comment: the column is int auto_increment lenght value 11

Comment: @ Webtecher, how do I do create table command syntax ,insert query?

Comment: Haw are you inserting new records? Are there any errors? Do you have atrigger on this table?

Comment: @ Devart, using bigint instead of int I'm able to continue my row inserts, before I using int I  was not able to. And no I don't have a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I change the id column from int to bigint, that allow me to go over the 999 row!

Comment: This is very strange, INT should allow you to have values of –2147483648 to 2147483647

Comment: @ FluffyKitten, that's what I read but it was not working in my case so I read several posts on how to allow tables large amounts of rows and I found out that a lot of people where using bigint instead of int for auto increase id fields, I gave it a try and it worked.